# How to create an Amazon SNS topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am trying to create an amazon SNS topic on the AWS console online, but i am getting the following error :
The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: OptInRequired; Request ID: dc64e7b8-ab93-512a-be3e-a86d4a25dbbc)
Can somebody help me with what i need to do, to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't subscribed to the Key Management Service or the Certificate Manager service. Contact AWS customer service and ask that they enroll you in those two services, and I believe that should correct the issue.

Comment: I tried contacting them before. The response from their side being "Unfortunately, the complexity of your question is outside our scope of knowledge here". Will try contacting again with this though!